# Access singleton bean directly from thymeleaf template?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

I am learning Spring, but it is confusing.

I have a singleton bean:

```
@Component
public class PuzzleUtil {
  @Bean
  @Scope("singleton")
  public PuzzleUtil puzzleUtil() {
    return new PuzzleUtil();
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getCategories() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In my web application class, when I load the index page, I am setting an attribute for the categories:

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class MathPuzzlesWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  @Autowired
  private PuzzleUtil puzzleUtil;
  
  @GetMapping("/index.html")
  public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("categories", puzzleUtil.getCategories());
    return "index";
  }

  // ...
}
```

Now, I can access the categories array in my index.html template:

```
        <table>
        <th:block th:each="category: ${categories}">
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${category}"></td>
        </tr>
        </th:block>
        </table>
```

Everything works as planned.

But, it seems adding the attribute to the model in my controller class is an extra step.  The bean is a singleton so I think I should be able to access it directly from my template.
I tried this:

```
<th:block th:each="category: ${puzzleUtil.categories}">
```

But, I get an error:

```
EL1007E: Property or field 'categories' cannot be found on null
```

Am I missing something or is it not possible to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using @ symbol with bean in thymeleaf

```
<th:block th:each="category: ${@puzzleUtil.getCategories()}">
```